# For loop in PHP with a unique output for only one loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a project where I have inputs that decide the range of numbers echoed but I also need to have a single number echo more text. At the moment I have an if statement which works but echoes the number a second time.

```
for ($x = $var1; $x <= $var2; $x += $varInc) {
    echo "<p>$x</p>";
    if ($x == $varGhost){
        echo "<p class='fas fa-ghost'></p>";
    }
}
```

It's supposed to look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: It echoes the number a second time? It doesn't look like it would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code to:

```
for ($x = $var1; $x <= $var2; $x += $varInc) {
 if ($x == $varGhost){
    echo "<p>$x - GHOST!</p>";
 } else {
    echo "<p>$x</p>";
 }
}
```

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working as expected because the second line echoes the number $x in any case, regardless the following `if` statement:

```
for ($x = $var1; $x <= $var2; $x += $varInc) {
    echo "<p>$x</p>"; // this line echoes the number $x in any case
    if ($x == $varGhost) {
        echo "<p class='fas fa-ghost'></p>";
    }
}
```

You should check the value of $x before printing it like this:

```
for ($x = $var1; $x <= $var2; $x += $varInc) {
    if ($x == $varGhost) {
        echo "<p class='fas fa-ghost'></p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>$x</p>"; // this line echoes the number $x ONLY if it isn't a ghost
    }
}
```

Anyway, a shorter way to write it:

```
for ($x = $var1; $x <= $var2; $x += $varInc)
    echo ($x == $varGhost) ? "<p class='fas fa-ghost'></p>" : "<p>$x</p>"
```

Hope it helps :)